# Лишние символы в URL

Tags: php, rest, mamp

Сорян за нубовские вопросы, но решения не нашел.
Вникаю в разработку `REST API`, использую `PHP STORM + MAMP` 
Файл `index.php` :

```
  <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    echo "GET";
} elseif  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo "POST";
}
```

По идее все должно быть нормально но к `URL` в браузере добавлятся какие то дефолтные символы, вот так выглядит `URL` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это пофиксить, чтобы было все чисто, и правильно прописать эти маршруты?

Comment: пока вы не начали изобретать велосипеды, посмотрите на библиотеку zend-diactors хотя бы

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами настраивали пошаговую отладку в PHPStorm. Ну так вот она эти символы и добавляет.

Ничего "фиксить" не нужно.

Comment: ну как же не нужно :-), хочется чтобы было красивенько без этих абракадабр, что же это за АПИ такое будет, когда вместо `/a/b/` , будет `/a?cdc=lkfjlwej`.